# When restoring disk in DiskUtility.app, showing error “the volume on device dev disk2(source volume) is not of type Apple_HFS or Apple_UFS”

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, migration, hfs

I got a new MacBook and now I’m trying to make an exact copy(clone) of my old Mac to the new Mac. Tried migration assistant, but I found it not reliable since there are still a lot of settings in my iTerm.app are lost, let alone some configurations of the system such as login iterms.

So I’m thinking to put my old Mac to target disk mode and connect two macs and use the disk utility app in recovery mode to restore my new mac’s hard drive from my old Mac.

While doing this, the disk utility returned an error showing “The volume on device /dev/disk2/ is not of type Apple_HFS or Apple_UFS. Could not validate source - Device not configured”. Note that /dev/disk2 is the source volume, namely my old mac’s disk. I then tried using asr and it showed me the same error message in Terminal.

I guess this thing should be related to this Apple’s new file system APFS or what, but the main question is how I can solve this problem?

Ps: tried dd copy also, but the new Mac won’t boot after the clone.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I'd go back to Migration Assistant... make sure you do it at initial setup, otherwise you'll end up with two accounts. [In fact, make sure that's not why your first attempt failed.]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks man! Yea I tried Migration Assistant again but still, I got some glitches, so I solved my problem by: bought a new hard drive, 1TB WD Password around $60, and restored my disk by saving it as a dmg file in the hard drive, and it didn't show any error this time. I then restored this disk image back to the hard disk in my new MacBook, and then since it cannot boot, I reinstalled macOS, and now everything seems smoothly transferred! I am so happy :D

Comment: @klanomath Yes I am editing it and just deleted it to "hide" the question. I was afraid of confusing some potential repliers so that's why I'm hiding it :) it will be back in a few minutes. Thanks again!